# Does enabling controller support in CSGO mess with Mouse and Keyboard settings?

Tags: controllers, counter-strike-global-offensive

I play CSGO with mouse and keyboard but I am curious how this game plays with an Xbox 360 controller. I know I need to use `exec controller.360.cfg` followed by `joystick 1` in the developer console to enable controller but I am afraid that it might mess up my mouse and keyboard configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never touched it before by adding more stuff to it, **it's safe to use**.

By default that config contains no keybinds for the mouse or keyboard. So if it's still untouched you should not lose or mess up any of your previous keybinds. This config mostly contains *joy_...* settings next to some keybinds exclusively for controllers and a few hud settings, so it's pretty much harmless.

If you have an own config file for your settings this won't mess up anything for you anyway. Custom files will never be overwritten by the game. So if you're still afraid that using this config will harm your game in any way: make a backup of your config or use a custom file and load (exec) it in your default config.